# how to condition nums row in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

helo i have database

[image]

[image]

```
 id|    tgl    | keterangan |id_user
 1  2021-03-01     in          3
```

and here I make insert validation into the database, I have insert parameters, namely:

```
  $id_user    = sesssion id_user post
  $tgl        = date('Y-m-d');
  $keterangan = $this->input->post('keterangan');
```

I create conditions before input to the database

```
$query = "SELECT id_user FROM db_ku WHERE  tgl = '$tgl' AND id_user = '$id_user' AND keterangan ='in' ";
$cek = $this->db->query($query)->num_rows();

$query1 = "SELECT id_user FROM db_ku WHERE  tgl = '$tgl' AND id_user = '$id_user' AND keterangan ='out' ";
$cek2 = $this->db->query($query1)->num_rows();

if ($cek > 0) {
    $message = array(
        'status'     => false,
        'message'    => 'you are already in'
    );
    echo messsage 
}
else if ($cek2 > 0) {
$message = array(
    'status'     => false,
    'message'    => 'you are already out'
);
echo messsage 
}else{
       
 $data = array(
    'tgl'           => $tgl,
    'keterangan'    => $keterangan,
    'id_user'       => $id_user,
);
$this->model_xx->insert_data($data);
$message = array(
    'status'     => true,
    'message'    => 'success',
    'data'       => $data
);
//insert db
        
}
```

I want to create conditions when posting data ..

if today (date now) id_user is already in, then insert in fails,

if today (date now) id_user is out then insert fails,

is there something wrong with my code?
because today I input data with 'keterangan' -> out , which reads the first condition

Comment: The code as you have shown it, won’t even execute, due to the parse errors it contains. And `echo` is not an appropriate tool to output a full array in one go.

Answer (score 0):

I reconstructed your code a bit to make it valid syntax (and a bit shorter).

```
<?php
// create default
$message = [
    'status' => false,
    'message' => 'you are already '
];

// default query
$query = $this->db->select('id_user')
    ->from('db_ku')
    ->where('CAST(tgl as DATE)', $tgl)
    ->where('id_user', $id_user);

if($query->where('keterangan', 'in')->get()->num_rows() > 0){
    // add to message
    $message['message'] = $message['message'] . 'in';
    // show message
    echo $message['message'];
} elseif($query->where('keterangan', 'out')->get()->num_rows() > 0){
    // add to message
    $message['message'] = $message['message'] . 'out';
    // show message
    echo $message['message'];
} else {
    // insert new and check if insert ID is returned
    if(is_int($this->model_xx->insert_data([
        'tgl' => $tgl,
        'keterangan' => $keterangan,
        'id_user' => $id_user
    ]))){
        // change message contents to success
        $message = [
            'status' => true,
            'message' => 'success',
            'data' => $data
        ];
    } else {
        // set message
        $message['message'] = 'Could not insert.';
        // show message
        echo $message['message'];
    }
}
```

Also i 'casted' your date to make sure that it is formatted correctly. I don't know your database column settings.

Also it's always good practice to return an boolean or an insert value from your query.

So your query should look something like this:

```
// insert query
function insert_data($arr){
    if(!isset($arr)){ return false; }
    // change table name for your table
    if($this->db->insert('table_name', $arr)){
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    } else { return false; }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your query and tb table? Maybe something is wrong there?

Comment: i update bro , cek my posting .. thanks @hixlax

Comment: great! Im think i see the problem. The colum waktu (time) cannot be empty, yet you're not giving it any value, so the insert would fail automaticly because your database expects one aditional value.